# Pandas resample daily to weekly data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I want to divide the daily data into 5 groups. Each starts from a different day with a fixed frequency of 5 business days. It's something like all the Monday put together and all the Tuesday put together. I use the `resample` function.

```
df1 = df.resample('5B').first()
df2 = df.resample('5B', offset=1).first()
df3 = df.resample('5B', offset=2).first()
```

I was expecting that `df1` starts from, let's say, 2000-01-03, `df2` starts from 2000-01-04 and `df3` starts from 2000-01-05. But the result shows that both `df2` and `df3` start from 2000-01-03. Is my understanding of `offset` wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a DataFrame with the date as index and datetime type. For instance `df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(32)}, index=pd.date_range('2000-01-03', '2000-02-03'))`

If you want to split your data by weekday, use [`dt.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) (`0`->`Monday` to `6`->`Sunday`) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in a dictionary comprehension (or a loop for saving to file):

```
dfs = {f'df{i+1}': d
       for i,d in df.groupby(df.index.weekday)
       if i<6}
```

Example output:

```
{'df1':             col
 2000-01-03    0
 2000-01-10    7
 2000-01-17   14
 2000-01-24   21
 2000-01-31   28,
 'df2':             col
 2000-01-04    1
 2000-01-11    8
 2000-01-18   15
 2000-01-25   22
 2000-02-01   29,
 'df3':             col
 2000-01-05    2
 2000-01-12    9
 2000-01-19   16
 2000-01-26   23
 2000-02-02   30,
 'df4':             col
 2000-01-06    3
 2000-01-13   10
 2000-01-20   17
 2000-01-27   24
 2000-02-03   31,
 'df5':             col
2000-01-07    4
 2000-01-14   11
 2000-01-21   18
 2000-01-28   25,
 'df6':             col
 2000-01-08    5
 2000-01-15   12
 2000-01-22   19
 2000-01-29   26}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you happen to know what went wrong with the resample method?